# I want to align the full screen Red box under the Nav bar but when I apply flex properties it get disturb

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to align the full screen Red box under the Nav bar but when I apply flex properties it get disturb .I tried almost every thing but it couldn't help in fixing my problem..
.
**what I really want is that the red box get 100% width and it should be responsive as well**

I think I donesomething wrong with my  Nav bar ?????????

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Shahmir's  CV </title>
        <link rel = "icon" href="images/cv.png" type="image/x-icon"> 
        <mata charaset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cv.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>




    <style>
      
      
       #home{
         background-image: url(images/1.jpg);
         background-size:cover;
         height: 100vh; /*           i use vh unit becouse to make it fit in the screen               */
         
         z-index: -1;      
         margin-top: -72px;
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column; 
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;/**/
       }
       #center{
       }

        </style>



    <body>
        
        

                  <!--************************************************************************************************************-->

                 <!-----------------------------          NAVBAR                  ------------------------------------------------->



                 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" >
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: white;" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li ><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </nav>

               

  
               <!-----------------------------          /NAVBAR                  ------------------------------------------------->


               


               <!----------------------------            home                 ------------------------------------------------------>



               <div class="bg-danger text-white" id="home">
                <div id="center">
                  <font color="white">shahmir</font>
                </div>
             </div>

            <!----------------------------------------           /home                 -------------------------------------------------- -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing you declare a width on #home.  This fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing, you just need to give ti width 100% only. If anything else needed or you want to ask, feel free to comment,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Shahmir's  CV </title>
        <link rel = "icon" href="images/cv.png" type="image/x-icon"> 
        <mata charaset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cv.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>




    <style>
      
      
       #home{
         background-image: url(images/1.jpg);
         background-size:cover;
         height: 100vh; /*           i use vh unit becouse to make it fit in the screen               */
         
         z-index: -1;      
         margin-top: -72px;
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column; 
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;/**/
width: 100%;
       }
       #center{
       }

        </style>



    <body>
        
        

                  <!--************************************************************************************************************-->

                 <!-----------------------------          NAVBAR                  ------------------------------------------------->



                 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" >
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: white;" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li ><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </nav>

               

  
               <!-----------------------------          /NAVBAR                  ------------------------------------------------->


               


               <!----------------------------            home                 ------------------------------------------------------>



               <div class="bg-danger text-white" id="home">
                <div id="center">
                  <font color="white">shahmir</font>
                </div>
             </div>

            <!----------------------------------------           /home                 -------------------------------------------------- -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```